# Wpf DataGridTextColumn With Element Style And ReadOnly

Tags: wpf, datagridtextcolumn

I need to disable editing on specific column based on a trigger ,but is not working.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Qty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="QTY" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Right"></Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemType}" Value="Discount">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Right"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemType}" Value="Discount">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Comment: it throws exception when I try to edit the cell 
'TextBlock' TargetType does not match type of element 'TextBox'.

Comment: now the horizontal Alignment is not working , is working only if I edit the cell  . When you leave from the cell the alignment is set to left instead to the right, that's why I  have set the Element style to TextBlock before. 
I also try Horizontal Content Alignment but still nothing.